# Как сделать что бы компоненты в PickerView были цикличными, как в будильнике от Apple?

Tags: swift, uiview

Было предположение, что есть какое-нибудь свойство, вроде Bool isCyclical, но ничего подобного не нашёл...

//Код

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var myPicker = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    myPicker.center = self.view.center
    
    //delegate
    myPicker.dataSource = self
    myPicker.delegate = self
    
    self.view.addSubview(myPicker)
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return 24
    } else if component == 1 {
        return 60
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if row < 10 {
        return "0\(row)"
    } else {
        return "\(row)"
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(50)
}
```

}

//

[image: Что получается]

[image: Как хочу сделать]

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, что там лучше использовать UIDateView и у UIDatePickerMode = выбрать необходимое значение и он по дефолту будет таким, как на 2-й картинке